# regexp replace with forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I can't understand for the life of me which this isn't replacing normal/ in the str. I imagine there is a way to escape it but everything i've tried doesn't seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/KU6U5/

```
str = 'http://www.foobar.com/foo/normal/a.jpg';

var usedPreSizeRangeRegExp = new RegExp("(tn/tn_|tn_med/|normal/|lrg/lrg_|'original/)$");

strd = str.replace(usedPreSizeRangeRegExp, "");
alert(strd);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`normal/` isn't located at the end of the string and the `$` in your regex requires it.

Try

```
var usedPreSizeRangeRegExp = new RegExp("(tn/tn_|tn_med/|normal/|lrg/lrg_|'original/)");
```

[RegexPal demo](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28tn/tn_%7Ctn_med/%7Cnormal/%7Clrg/lrg_%7C%27original/%29&input=http://www.foobar.com/foo/normal/a.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

`normal/` will never match because you have `$` at the end of your regular expression which matches the **end** of the string. Since `normal/` doesn't occur near the end at all, this will never match.

Removing the `$` and changing the regular expression to:

```
new RegExp("(tn/tn_|tn_med/|normal/|lrg/lrg_|'original/)")
```

does work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6ZD2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can escape `/` with a `\` so you would get `\/`. You added a `$` at the end, which means, that only match everything at the end of the string, but the string doesn't end with any of the options, so there wont be any matches.

```
var str = 'http://www.foobar.com/foo/normal/a.jpg';
var strd = str.replace(/(tn\/tn_|tn_med\/|normal\/|lrg\/lrg_|'original\/)/, "");
```

Comment: / doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: It needs to be escaped in RegExp literals.

Comment: Ah yeah I overlooked that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = 'http://www.foobar.com/foo/normal/a.jpg';

var usedPreSizeRangeRegExp = new RegExp("(tn\/tn_|tn_med\/|normal\/|lrg\/lrg_|'original\/)");

strd = str.replace(usedPreSizeRangeRegExp, "");
alert(strd);
```